# Use different names for the same method in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax

I use Angular7 and I have added lazy loading and guards for some routes.

Since I use lazy loading I need both CanLoad and CanActivate guards which use the same logic. Here is my guard class:

```
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate {

  public canActivate = (): boolean => {
    // some logic which returns current user auth status 
  };

  public canLoad = this.canActivate;

}
```

Is there any way to simplify this syntax?
Is it possible to write something like that:

```
public canActivate, public canLoad = (): boolean => { // some logic}
```

My code is working, but I feel like I am missing something. I also understand that guard canLoad may be abundand, because user will not be able to navigate the protected route anyway. So this is a question about syntax rather than about anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a function as the handler for a router rule and avoid the use of a class all together.

```js
function LoggedInGuard(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   return true;
}

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: 'team/:id',
          component: TeamComponent,
          canActivate: ['LoggedInGuard'],
          canLoad: ['LoggedInGuard']
        }
      ])
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'LoggedInGuard',
        useValue: LoggedInGuard
      }
    ]
  })
```

If your rule depends upon dependency injection (such as a UsersService), then you could try using a factory to create a function (but I have not tested this).

```js
function LoggedInGuardFactory(users: UsersService) {
   return (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
      return users.isAllowed();
   }
}

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: 'team/:id',
          component: TeamComponent,
          canActivate: ['LoggedInGuard'],
          canLoad: ['LoggedInGuard']
        }
      ])
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'LoggedInGuard',
        useFactory: LoggedInGuardFactory,
        deps: [UsersService]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Comment: It is definitely not a good decision to put this function into a module. But using factory for class is a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I see this working

```
const b = (): boolean => {  return true }

class test{
   public canActivate = b;
   public canLoad = b;
}
```

Comment: I also thought about it. Unfortunately, it uses instance of service. I didn't mention that. However, I could use this pattern together with factory inside class. Thank you!